# Unable to send message received by one client to all other clients connected to the server

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am working on a small project related to Network Programming in C. I was trying to make a simple group chat program where in multiple clients concurrently connect to a single server, and whenever any of the clients write a message, the server will send that a message to all other clients.

In short, it is a group chat, in which all clients connected to a server can communicate with each other. However, I'm having a weird issue that I'm unable to figure out.

What I'm doing is: Run server -> Run client 1 -> Run client 2 -> Run client 3 -> Now when client 1 types a message, no other client receives that message -> When client 2 types a message, only client 1 receives that message -> When client 3 types a message, both client 1 & client 2 receives that message.

It is, for some weird reason, working in a way that messages by a client will only be sent to those clients that connected to the server before this client. As client 3 connected after 1 & 2, 1 & 2 received 3rd client's messages, however 3rd client does not get any message by the 2nd client.

The following is the code I use in my server.c file:

```
    comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);
    arr[count++] = comm_fd;
    printf("Client %d connected to the server!\n",comm_fd);
    if ( (childpid = fork ()) == 0 ) { /*0 means child process*/
        do {
        read(comm_fd,recvline,100);
        printf("Client %d: %s",comm_fd,recvline);
        if(strcmp(sendline,"bye\n") == 0) {
          printf("Client %d left the chat!\n",comm_fd);
          close(comm_fd);
          exit(4);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
          if(arr[i]!=comm_fd) {
            write(arr[i],recvline,strlen(recvline)+1);
          }
        }
      } while(1);
    }
```

And this is my client.c:

```
  fgets(sendline,100,stdin);
  write(sockfd,sendline,strlen(sendline)+1);
  if(strcmp(sendline,"bye\n") == 0) {
    printf("Closing connection!\n");
    exit(4);
  }
  bzero( sendline, 100);
  if ( (childpid = fork ()) == 0 ) {
    do{
      read(sockfd,recvline,100);
      printf("%s",recvline);
      if(strcmp(recvline,"bye\n") == 0) {
        printf("\nA client left the chat group!\n\n");
        exit(4);
      }
      bzero( recvline, 100);
    } while(1);
  }
```

Can anyone help me with this? I searched a lot for a solution to this issue but could not find an answer. I'm new to socket programming so I really need help with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `fork()` is probably the wrong model for such a server. Think about the state of the `arr[]` array each time a new connection is accepted and a new child is forked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is, for some weird reason, working in a way that messages by a
>   client will only be sent to those clients that connected to the server
>   before this client

That behavior makes sense to me -- fork() creates a child process whose memory/state is a copy of the current state of the parent process, which means that any changes to the parent process (such as the acceptance of a new client connection) that occur after the fork() call will not be propagated to the existing child processes.  Therefore each child process will "see" only the clients that were already connected when its own sub-process was created via fork().

Comment: Makes sense to me as well (Y) Is there any way to update changes to forked child processes?

Comment: Sure, you could communicate with it via its stdin file descriptor, or via sockets or pipes or whatnot.  I agree with keithmo's comment though, this sort of thing would be more easily and simply implemented within a single process (e.g. via select() event loop or via multithreading) than via multiprocesses and fork().  The process-spaces separation is working against you and not gaining you very much.